# Radius of convergence $r$ of complex power series

Tags: complex-analysis, convergence-divergence, solution-verification, power-series

I want to show this proposition :
if $\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k(z-z^*)^k$ is a complex power series of convergence's radius $r$ then it converges normally $\forall z \in D(z^*,r) $ and diverges $\forall z \in \mathbb C \backslash \overline{D}(z^*,r)$.

I did the following :
To show the normal convergence on $D(z^*,r)$ I need to show that $\forall z \in D(z^*,r)$, $\exists \epsilon > 0$  such that $\overline{D} (z,\epsilon) \subset U$ and $$\sum_{k=0}^\infty \sup_{x \in \overline{D}(z,\epsilon)}\{ {\lvert a_k(x-z^*)^k \rvert} \} < \infty$$

We know that since $D(z^*,r)$ is open, $\forall z \in D(z^*,r), \exists \delta > 0$ such that $C:=\overline{D}(z,\frac\delta2) \subset D(z,\delta)\subset D(z^*,r)$.

Now $$\sum_{k=0}^\infty \sup_{z \in C}\{ {\lvert a_k(z-z^*)^k \rvert} \} <\sum_{k=0}^\infty  {\lvert a_k\rvert r^k } < \infty$$

Is it correct ?

Comment: The assertion “converges normally $\forall z \in D(z^*,r)$” makes no sense. It should be simply “converges normally in $D(z^*,r)$”.

Comment: yes you are right in fact this notion is relative to a set and not a point (like continuity for example)